# Vim: How do determine where/when a key mapping is set?

Tags: vim, configuration, editor, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts

I've found a mapping in the output of `:map` that I'd like to remove, but I have no idea where the mapping is being set.

Is there a way to find out where/when a mapping is set so that I can remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this command:

```
:verbose map <key>
```